# Is there an Open Source HTML renderer written in C#?

Tags: c#, html

I started to write a HTML renderer in C# just as a learning exercise. I managed to get the simple stuff like bold and headers going. In doing so I bumped into a number of problems and I hoping I could have a look at how other people got around those problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://khaos.codeplex.com/ is a project on codeplex. they trying to create wpf-based rendrer.

Answer (score 4):

You can try http://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/ . This is a library of 100% managed code that draws beautifully formatted HTML.

Comment: I have used this also and must say its very nicely laid out, clear and concise.

Answer (score 2):

I forked https://github.com/LayoutFarm/HtmlRenderer from the original
Html-Renderer project, and added more HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript. It is under development, and has bugs; test it out, and feel free to comment, fork, discuss.

snapshot:  nearly pass ACID1 
[image]

---

compare with ACID1 reference on wikipedia
[image: acid1_reference]

(from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid1)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is 'no'. Have a look at [Chris Cavanagh’s blog entry](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2009/08/25/wpf-chromium-webbrowser-source-code/) on how he embedded the Chrome HTML renderer into his WPF application. You will probably have to do something similar

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pieter. The thing is that I am looking for the rendering code, not for something to render it for me.