# How to get an image byte array from an HTML string in C#?

Tags: c#

The requirement is to get an image byte from the HTML string. input: HTML string and type(png,jpg) Output: byte[] Any suggestions?

Below added the sample HTML string

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

As I need to pass this byte array to itextSharp for further processing, I need the output as an image byte array.

previously I have used the GetImageFromHTML functionality provided by winnowative. Now we are replacing Winnowative and need an alternative for getting the image bytes.
See the winnowative code below.

```
public static byte[] GetWinnovativeImageByte(string htmlString)
        {
            byte[] pdfBytes = null;
            pdfBytes = wImg.GetImageBytesFromHtmlString(htmlString, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);//wpc.GetPdfBytesFromHtmlString(htmlString);//, baseURL);
            return pdfBytes;
        }
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you've already tried that you can share with us?

Comment: You need to mark html as code, as it will be interpreted as part of the post otherwise.

Comment: There is no image tag in your example. So, you are done. Return an emtpy byte[] :D

Comment: It is not at all clear what you actually mean. Is the goal to *render* the html to produce an image? Draw the html string to a new bitmap? Find an image tag and download a image from the address? You should also explain what research you have done to solve the problem and what you have attempted so far. Just posting an assignment without any attempt at solving it is frowned upon.

Comment: My requirement is not to get extracted images from an HTML String. Actually, the HTML should be converted to an image and get the byte array from that image.

Comment: @Fildor yes there are no images in the provided HTML. The provided HTML should be converted to an image in a particular format png /jpg and the byte array should be the image that was generated using the input HTML

Comment: @Fildor previously I have used the GetImageFromHTML functionality that provided by winnowative. Now we are replacing Winnowative and need an alternative for getting the image bytes. Added an screenshot of the sample code above.

Comment: The word you are looking for is "rendering". You want an image of the rendered HTML. Not sure if this is possible with a Browser Component, _maybe_ with some HTML library. But that's not my cup of tea, honestly. So, someone else may have a good idea.

Comment: Praveen, you could embed a browser control, and call navigate() method passing this htmlString, and then somehow invoke the print dialog on that browser control, save it as pdf. Or find some library that will do it for you :-)

Comment: Code screenshot ‍♂️, out of guidelines (search for software recommandation) and duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567207 (aka you didn't even ask Google in first place...)

Comment: @JonasH I want an image-byte array of the rendered HTML. I have tried various approaches and tried converting the HTML to an image first and then converting the image to a byte array. But this requires saving the image to a local directory.  Actually, I need this byte array without saving this image to a local path. Any suggestions?

Comment: You you have an image you do not need to save it to disk to get a byte array. But if you have managed to successfully create an image, and wants to know how to convert an image to a byte array, **make the question about that**! That the image is from HTML could be useful as *background information*. If you are using a third party library to render the HTML you will be limited to whatever API this provides. Either work within these limitations or find another library.